# Is there an STL adaptor on iterator invoking callback for each collection element?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I am especially interested in adaptor for a following use case:

```
std::list<int> input {1, 2, 3};
std::list<int> result;
auto l = [](auto e) { return e + 1; };
result.insert(result.end(), adaptor(input.begin(), l), adaptor(input.end(), l));
// now result == {2, 3, 4}
```

It would be nice if the adaptor would not use external libraries (e.g. boost).

Comment: like `std::transform` with a back inserter ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I think this is exactly what I was looking for... Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So using PiotrSkotnicki advice I end up with a code like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

int main() {
   std::list<int> input {1, 2, 3};
   std::list<int> output;
   std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(output), [](auto e){ return e + 1;});
}
```

Comment: You can use `std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [](auto e){ return e + 1;});`, it will auto-append elements without the need of `resize`

Comment: You should add a call to `output.reserve(input.size())` before the call to transform.

Comment: @Shloim I don't think there is an vector::reserve equivalent for a list unfortunately, but if there is it would definitely improve efficiency...

Comment: My mistake. Thought we were dealing with vectors.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is tagged C++14, and says that no external library dependence would be great (fair enough).

For future reference, though, note that the [`range`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library seems well on its way toward adoption by the standard library (the [C++17 range for loop is already compliant with one of its major points](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)). So, using `range`, the code could look like this:

```
#include <list>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main() {
    const std::list<int> input{1, 2, 3};
    const std::list<int> result = 
        input | ranges::view::transform([](int i){ return i + 1; });
}
```

and it's what future standard library C++ code is likely to be. Irrespectively, it has its advantages:

- It looks more intuitive (although that might be subjective).
- Note how you can make `result` `const`.

Comment: Generally I am opened for external libraries but the project I'm stuck with needs to be as light as possible... Your approach is very straightforward and if I wasn't as limited I would definitely choose the code from your answer